# Why does my NSBox draw a background? (boxType = .primary)

Tags: cocoa, nsbox

I realized that suddenly (without me touching the corresponding code) my `NSBox` has a double visualization. It is as if the Box has a background color and draws its normal rounded frame inside. I added a small screenshot. The parent control is white, the `NSBox` is gray with the title "Inputs" (unchanged `titlePosition`). Under the title is the normal box, adding a 2nd shade of gray.

[image: A NSBox with a double frame]

I did not change any of the usual suspects, especially not `boxType` which is still set to `.primary`.

I did work on the Dark Mode (Dark Aqua) but cannot see any change that would cause this behaviour. `effectiveAppearance` is still `Aqua`.

Answer (score 0):

A NSBox with a boxType of `.primary` always draws a background. That is intended behaviour. Only if the view behind NSBox is white you may not see it. If you want a NSBox without background you must make it boxType  `.custom` and set the background color as required.

Comment: Interesting. I didn’t notice before. Are you sure? The background was always white.

Comment: Yes, you can reproduce this easily in Interface Builder if you add a .primary NSBox to a .custom NSBox and change the color of the .custom box in the background. Dependent on the .custom box background color the color of the .primary box can fade to invisible white.